# Please explain the origin of "mitgehen lassen"

Tags: etymology, idiom

I recently came across (paraphrasing) *Das habe ich aus dem Hinterzimmer des Ladens mitgehen lassen.* Apparently *mitgehen lassen* is an idiomatic and euphemistic way of saying "to pilfer". I'm wondering how the literal meaning connects to the idiomatic meaning. It sounds like the item followed the person out of the store like a lost puppy; is that a fair interpretation? There are entries in Redensarten-Index and English (not German, for some reason) Wiktionary, but neither gives any explanation for the origin.

Comment: "It sounds like the item followed the person out of the store like a lost puppy; is that a fair interpretation?" Basically, yes. And the person didn't prevent that, even encouraged it.

Comment: There is a very similarly structured idiomatic phrase you might be interested in as well: [*etw. rüberwachsen lassen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rueberwachsen) = 'to hand sth. over'. Again, it features *lassen* as if the object would hand over itself (like in case of *mitgehen lassen*: steal itself)

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Thanks. I'm not sure I can reconcile "hand over" and "grow over", but some idioms are just unexplainable.

Comment: @RDBury Just to be sure: the expression is rankly jocular as well. Of course a chewing gum, e.g., can't 'grow over', but for this very reason I find the mechanism behind 'to let sth. grow over' (*rüberwachsen lassen*) the same as with 'to let sth. come along' (*mitgehen lassen*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> to be dragged along with something else

is simply a literal meaning of "[mitgehen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/mitgehen)", meaning 2.). Also frequently used to describe processes that have side effects.

Example, very up-to-date:

> Bei dem Hochwasser gingen Sträucher, Bäume, Autos und sogar Häuser mit.

Thus "Das habe ich mitgehen lassen" simply translates to

> I allowed or didn't prevent or used little effort that this one got dragged along with me

with "lassen" introducing a passive, trivialising aspect. It can have a few meanings in English, here an apt one would probably be "to allow".

In the end, it means

> I stole this.

Comment: yes, like *jmd. mitnehmen, erfassen (mit dem Auto)*. The question was basicly where that's from. It is not from the DWDS, is it? And it says nothing about *lassen*

Comment: desch hascht dir em ausgdocht

Comment: So you're saying the item got caught up in the wake as the person left, like a leaf in the wake of a speeding car. Or somehow the item got stuck to the person by static electricity, and it wasn't noticed until it was too late. As similar expression in English is "it fell of the back of a truck", but while both the speaker and the hearer know there was no truck, the story is plausible enough that both can pretend it's true. I guess the German is more humorous than euphemistic.

Comment: @RDBury We don't speak about the details of the physical interaction, that would be unprofessional :-). Yep, "Ist vom Laster gefallen" is actually the same in German. Maybe an English equivalent for "hab' ich mitgehen lassen" could be "Got a five finger discount for this" ?

Comment: @a_donda: Yes, I see that *vom Laster gefallen* is used. It doesn't seem that common though; perhaps it's translated from the English phrase. I wonder if *vom LKW gefallen* would also work. The English version of where I got this from uses "snag", which leaves the impression that it somehow go tangled up with you as you were leaving. "Snag" can also just mean "take", but perhaps it originally meant something along the lines of *mitgehen lassen*.

Comment: I didn't know translation was the target of the question, but if *let go* is *to let loose*, maybe it's better to ignore the passive and refer to slipping, *he slipped it into his pocket*, which is also impossible to translate back with etymology: 1. *? er schlüpfte \*es (in seine Tasche)* might be unetymologic 2. *er schleifte es... *; *mitschleifen, mitgeschliffen werden* is covered by the definition in this answer. 3. *schlagen* (cp. *slew*, *schlug*, equiv. *sich die Taschen voll hauen*).Conclusion,*(sch)lagen* is \*lV- + \*gana. Bazinga! Also see *lupfen* "lift", abziehen, zocken, hauen

Comment: @RDBury: LKW "Elkaweh" is not an everyday word like Laster because it's a bit unwieldy, needs more involvement of the speech organ. There is, though, a local version, that's in Swabia, where LKW written on a sign in front of a bakery means "Leberkäsweck", and I won't take the fun of looking it up yourself :-)

Comment: @a_donda: I thought *LKW* was more common, at least it's the term I'm more familiar with, though that means little. So *Leberkäse* contains neither liver or cheese, but people fry it up, put it on a bun and call it "LKW". I think the closest thing to it that's available where I am is SPAM :)

Comment: SPAM, exactly, yeuch :-) ! LKW discussion doesn't belong here, so I leave it. See you next question :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitgehen) lists the meaning at least, but the corresponding lexeme page is not yet created.

Note, that *mitgehen lassen* as non-idiom means "permit sombody to walk with someone" (i.e. accompany him/her) and any [corpora hit](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=kern&from=wb&h=1&q=mitgehen%20lassen) earlier than ca. 1970 is likely to have that "normal" meaning.

I had considered the idiom as not much more than an euphemism, downplaying the own participation in the theft,  in the sense of "I did not reject something hopping into my bag".

Comment: Your right, it is in German Wiktionary under *Redewendungen*. The Egon Kisch quote is from 1925 and seems to use the idiomatic meaning, but the next one seems to be from 1972. That's kind of what I was thinking, "It hopped into my bag," "It fell into my pocket," "It followed me out," all have the same general idea that the person only "allowed" the item to do something.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a need to refer to "walking" instead of the more general "go".

*gehen lassen* is equivalent to *let go*, and the preposition *mit* implies a common direction.

The verbal phrase has a plain meaning: if a kid wants go with its friends to somewhere, the parents may let it, if the group will take it with them (compare *mitnehmen*).

A logical conclusion seems to be that it could be that it is ironic, self-reflexive, proposing command of the object to let it go. This might appear ironic or absurd.

It is offensive in the first place to assume command of the object, but the intent is usually kept secret in case of thieving. A thought crime, it is difficult to construct an *Abstraktes Gefährdungsdelikt*. Therefore, for all intents and purposes, everyone perceives the taking and going as infraction into somebody's possession, and calls it accordingly.

On top of that, *lassen* suggests that the action is effortless, as it should be to remain undetected.

That is to say, it only implies pilfering, as you say.

One might imagine that it had more basic implications, I'm wondering about dispatchers in logistics letting go a little extra for one reason or another, which might become collusion or criminal negligence to the detriment of the owner. Or it could be one of those infamous reinterpretations of Bargoens or other thieves cant, but that does not seem to be suggested. All things considered, it seems very literal.

Instead of a dog from a pet shop, it might also have referred to innocent children, I suppose, since kidnapping must have been rather lucrative at some point, in which case *verleiten* would have been a better choice of words,  compare *to lead*, *lead astray, lead away*, but I can't quite tell if this is related or not (computer says no).

Comment: "gehen lassen is equivalent to.let go" No, it's not. "let go" is equivalent to "loslassen".

Comment: Also, do you have some issue with your space bar?

Comment: @Roland what, are you complaining the pronoun is missing, "let sb. go"? Other than that, Yes, I installed a new touch keyboard with smaller spacebar.

Comment: No, I'm not. https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/let%20go

Comment: https://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/let+go.html

Comment: OK? Where do find a translation of "let sb. go" as "mitgehen" in that dictionary?

Comment: @Roland also, that alone doesn't invalidate the anser. Have to wonder eho let people like you vote (wait, was that wrong? Who allowet people like you to vote)? You yourself, you did. How dare you

Comment: Please don't make assumptions regarding who voted and how they voted. You are very likely to be wrong. I haven't cast a vote since 2019.

Comment: that does overall not make the downvotes any better. Also, liar liar

Comment: You can check yourself. You have voted 5 times this month. I have voted 0 times.

Comment: But if you prefer, I can make an exception and add a downvote.

Comment: pants 'n' f... oh, okay then.

Comment: Typos aside (oddly, "infraction" and *infraktion* are false friends), I like this answer. Yes, I was expecting any literal interpretation to be either ironic or absurd, possibly humorous. I think people do tend to ascribe thoughts to inanimate objects when they want to shift responsibility. It's a "suspension of disbelief" (*willentliche Aussetzung der Ungläubigkeit*), but a comforting one.

Comment: Note the qualifications, "... seems to be that it could be that it is ..." This is weak, albeit not mere speculation, but a reason why it is accepted (I vouche for myself) even if another original meaning is not recognizable.

Comment: @Roland be that as i may, actually I have to accept the fact that "let go" is primarily used as you said, other interpretatios like the literal SoP not with standing, because that is just my point: nothing to do with *walking* per se. It's playing into my cards all the more, given previous threads on "lass gehen", if *let's go* would not immediately allow analogy in *let him go*, that I argue this *'s* was not originally from *us*, and that *lass ma' * was not originally from *mal* ("once", "times").